# R to return the occurrence of each unique value

Tags: frequency

I have a list of numbers

```
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   2   8   3   8   8   4   8   1
```

and I would like to use R to calculate each number's occurrence, so it look like the following

```
8   76%
2   6%
3   6%
4   6%
1   6%
```

Is there a quick way/function of doing this? Thank you.